# С помощью каких технологий можно сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке страницы вниз цвет diva менялся?

Tags: javascript, html5

Я знаю html, css и чутка js, где бы мне найти ответ на мой вопрос? Я плохо знаю js, чтобы с помощью него решить проблему. Может есть другие пути решения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это получится сделать с помощью библиотеки [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). Вообще я вам советую изучить JavaScript получше.

Вот самый простой пример: https://jsfiddle.net/ep6wrvrk/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    var step = $(document).scrollTop() / (document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight);
    $("#sidebar").css( "background-color", "rgb(" + Math.round(step*255) + ", 0, 0)" );
  });
});
```

На документ создается слежение за событием прокрутки, затем при прокрутке получаем коэффициент расстояния от начала документа до начала окна и уже манипулируем этим значением. В данном случае умножаем на макс. rgb значение и ставим его на красный канал, затем применяем как фоновый цвет div'а.

Answer (score -2):

Это слишком необычная операция, чтобы присутствовать в какой-либо библиотеке "из коробки". Вместе с тем, реализация на js предельно проста - повесить событие на прокрутку и пересчитать цвет div'a.

Возможно, это и правда можно решить при помощи css, но сомневаюсь, что решение будет кроссбраузерным.